# HTML to XHTML Mobile Profile Converter

Tags: linux, xhtml, xhtml-mp, mobile-browser

I looking for Linux Library/Service that can make conversion of supplied HTML to XHTML-MP format. It will be perfect if this library also know to make resizing of embedded images.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to clean up your html such that it becomes well formed.

Comment: It is definitely other product for different purposes.